# Memory Consumption while debugging a SP 2013 on-premises Solution

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, visual-studio-2013

Just wanted to know, how much memeory -RAM would be consumed when I debug a SP 2013 SP1 VISUAL WEB PART/ ITEM EVENT RECEIVER/ TIMERJOB  kind of on-premise solutions  for an environment like below:

1. 16 GB RAM
2. 150 GB IN C: DRIVE
3. WINDOWS SERVER 2012 R2 AS OS
4. 2 CORE CPU
5. VISUAL STUDIO 2013 PROF. installed
6. SP DESIGNER 2013 INSTALLED ON this dev machine
7. Sharepoint Manager also installed
8. CAML DESIGNER 2013
9. SQL SERVER IS IN DIFFERENT SERVER

Please let me know any other environmental factors will be affecting the debugging/memory consumption , so that I can provide the same.

Comment: That would depend a lot on what your solution is doing. Say you are manipulating a huge list, then you would be consuming a lot of memory if you don't take the right measures to prevent it. But I would say that in general it doesn't consume a significant amount. 16 GB of memory is also the recommended amount for a dev environment by microsoft

Comment: is the sql server be present in the same env? or sql server as a separate install in anther server -  2 server spfarm env. Also if i am having 4 web applns created in the central admin , and i am doing the development for a list item event receiver./ timer job.  Is there any calculation involved in this? like , IIS  will consume xx amount of CPU/memory , VS  will consume xxxx amount of CPU / memory with 2 CORE CPU in my dev.

Comment: I don't know about any calculation, but you can check this to see if your environment is up for the task. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#hwLocServers